# Bill converted to smaller bills

Tags: javascript

If I enter 1234, it's getting divided by 2000. When I add a condition to check if the bill is < or > than 2000 other variables are getting undefined. I will post my original code. Any help is appreciated.

```js
let totalCash;

function amount(){
    let userInput = prompt('Enter amount');
    calculation(userInput)
}

function calculation(userInput){
    totalCash = parseInt(userInput);
    let twoTho = Math.round(totalCash / 2000);
    totalCash %= 2000;
    let oneTho = Math.round(totalCash / 1000);
    totalCash %= 1000;
    let fivHo = Math.round(totalCash / 500);
    totalCash %= 500;
    let twoHo = Math.round(totalCash / 200);
    totalCash %= 200;
    let oneHo = Math.round(totalCash / 100);
    totalCash %= 100;
    let fifthy = Math.round(totalCash / 50);
    totalCash %= 50;
    let ten = Math.round(totalCash / 10);
    totalCash %= 10;
    let two = Math.round(totalCash / 2);
    totalCash %= 2;
    let one = Math.round(totalCash / 1);
    totalCash %= 1;
    console.log(`Bills: \n ${twoTho} - $2000, \n ${oneTho} - $1000, \n ${fivHo} - $500, \n ${twoHo} - $200,\n ${oneHo} - $100, \n ${fifthy} - $50, \n ${ten} - $10, \n Coins: \n ${two} - $2, \n ${one} - $1`)
}


amount(1234);
```

Comment: `1234 / 2000` is `0.617`. You mistake is that you are _rounding_ here - `.617` rounds up to `1`. You want to _floor_ those fractions instead.

Comment: You should replace `let one = Math.round(totalCash / 1); totalCash %= 1;` with `let one = totalCash;`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.floor` insead of `Math.round`

```js
let totalCash;

function amount(){
    let userInput = prompt('Enter amount');
    calculation(userInput)
}

function calculation(userInput){
    totalCash = parseInt(userInput);
    let twoTho = Math.floor(totalCash / 2000);
    totalCash %= 2000;
    let oneTho = Math.floor(totalCash / 1000);
    totalCash %= 1000;
    let fivHo = Math.floor(totalCash / 500);
    totalCash %= 500;
    let twoHo = Math.floor(totalCash / 200);
    totalCash %= 200;
    let oneHo = Math.floor(totalCash / 100);
    totalCash %= 100;
    let fifthy = Math.floor(totalCash / 50);
    totalCash %= 50;
    let ten = Math.floor(totalCash / 10);
    totalCash %= 10;
    let two = Math.floor(totalCash / 2);
    totalCash %= 2;
    let one = Math.floor(totalCash / 1);
    totalCash %= 1;
    console.log(`Bills: \n ${twoTho} - $2000, \n ${oneTho} - $1000, \n ${fivHo} - $500, \n ${twoHo} - $200,\n ${oneHo} - $100, \n ${fifthy} - $50, \n ${ten} - $10, \n Coins: \n ${two} - $2, \n ${one} - $1`)
}


amount(1234);
```